# Action Listener detects multiple Events for a Single Event

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, actionlistener

I have designed a panel that includes some buttons with it. Buttons are attached with an ActionListener. When ever i click on that buttons this ActionListener detects 4 events for this single click. Whereas it should detect only one. Does anybody know what exactly the reason is?

```
public class Buttons extends JPanel
{
private JButton undo=new JButton("Undo");
private JButton replay=new JButton("Replay");

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    super.setSize(new Dimension(560,30));
    super.add(replay);
    super.add(undo);
    undo.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE,3));
    replay.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE,3));

    undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Controler.pieces.undo();
            Controler.reDraw();

        }
    });
    replay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Dastiii");
        }
    });

}
 }
```

and these events are being used here

```
public void undo()
{
    System.out.print(Controler.allMoves.size());
    if(Controler.allMoves.size()<=1)
    {
        init_board();
        return;
    }
    Piece temp[][]=Controler.allMoves.get(Controler.allMoves.size()-2);
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            board[i][j].set_name(temp[i][j].get_name());
            board[i][j].set_oneWay(temp[i][j].get_oneWay());
        }
    }
    Controler.allMoves.remove(Controler.allMoves.size()-2);
}
```

Comment: Add your code to the question.

Comment: Maybe it is detecting something like `buttonDown` `buttonPressed` `buttonUp` and some other one during a complete click.

Comment: @csmckelvey i have added actionlistener with buttons, **buttonDown** or some  others are linked to mouse listener i think. am i right?

Comment: You do mot control execution of `paint` method but you decided to add `ActionListener` there. So each time paint is called you **add another** `ActionListener` to your buttons..

Comment: Definitely check the answer from MadProgrammer.

Comment: Perhaps a good note is that the method is `addActionListener()` not `setActionListener()`. Adding the same listener multiple times has the intended effect of executing the handler multiple times when the button is activated (it does not overwrite or replace the previously registered ActionListener).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your registering you `ActionListener`s within the `paint` method!!

Let's not even worry about the fact that it's un-recommended to override `paint`

Never change or modify the state of the component or any of it's child components within in any `paint` method, these will be called multiple times during the execution of your application.  For example, it's not unusual for a `paint` method to be called 2-4 times just when the main window is made visible...

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    /** All this should be done within the constructor
    // If you are using a layout manager, this is pointless, if your not
    // then that's another problem
    super.setSize(new Dimension(560,30));
    super.add(replay);
    super.add(undo);
    undo.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE,3));
    replay.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE,3));

    undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Controler.pieces.undo();
            Controler.reDraw();

        }
    });
    replay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Dastiii");
        }
    });
    **/

}
```

Take a look at:

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

For more details about how and what painting is in Swing

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ohhhh... i see.. I got it..!! :)

Comment: @csmckelvey I looked right passed it to at first...think my sub subconscious was trying to protected me...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I need to develop my inner savior as well!